# Javascript timer receiving errors upon start

Tags: javascript, html, web

Input:

```
function timer() {
  decimal++;
  cs++;
  decimalOut.innerHTML = decimal;
  if (decimal >= 100) {
    decimal = 0;
    sec++;

    if (sec > 59) {
      sec = 0;
      min++;
      colon.innerHTML = ":";
      minOut.innerHTML = min;
    }
    if (sec <= 9 && min > 0) {
      sec = "0" + sec;
    }
    secOut.innerHTML = sec;
  }

  if (decimal <= 9) {
    decimal = '0' + decimal;
    decimalOut.innerHTML = decimal;
  }

}
window.onkeyup = run;

function run() {
  if (!running) {
    decimal = 0;
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
    cs = 0;
    secOut.innerHTML = "0";
    minOut.innerHTML = "";
    colon.innerHTML = "";
    running = true;
    scramble = "";
    generateScramble();
    interval = setInterval(timer, 10);
  } else if (running) {
    running = false;
    clearInterval(interval);
    timesDisplay.push(" " + timesOut.innerHTML);
    csTimes.push(cs);
    timesList.innerHTML = timesDisplay;
    calculateStats();
  }
}
```

Output:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null(…)

This error supposedly occurs on line 350 which is:

```
<div id="basicallyaholderthing" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:718px;width:801px;height:545px;z-index:11">
```

I also have a place for it:

```
<div id="timeOut"><span id="min"></span><span id="colon"></span><span id="sec">0</span>.<span id="decimal">00</span></div></br>
```

I have put the place where that output should be inside of the html holder. According to the error, it just doesn't work. Anyone know anything about this?

UPDATE*

Here is a list of most of the set vars.

```
var running = false;
var interval;
var decimal = 0;
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;
var cs = 0;
var decimalOut = document.getElementById("decimal");
var secOut = document.getElementById("sec");
var minOut = document.getElementById("min");
var colon = document.getElementById("colon");
var timesOut = document.getElementById("timeOut");
var timesList = document.getElementById("timeList");
var clearAll = document.getElementById("clear");
var timesDisplay = new Array();
var csTimes = new Array();
var avAll = 0;
var avAllOut = document.getElementById("overallAv");
var best = 999999999999999999;
var bestOut = document.getElementById("fastest");
var worst = 0;
var numSolves = 0;
var total = 0;
var numSolvesOut = document.getElementById("solveNum");
```

Comment: Some of your elements used in the js file does not exist.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: `decimalOut` doesn't exist. I don't see anywhere where you're setting it.

Comment: Ralf, they do exist, i just do not have my entire thing put it. i might have missed a few.

Comment: Imma add the vars into the main post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error tells you the exact problem:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null(…)

The line it's referring to is one of these:

```
decimalOut.innerHTML = decimal;
```

Therefore, `decimalOut` is set to `null`.

The reason why is hard to know 100% without seeing all of your code in one place, but the most likely cause is your initialization code:

```
var decimalOut = document.getElementById("decimal");
```

If that's causing it to be set to `null`, that means either:

1. There is no element in your DOM with the ID `decimal`
2. Your initialization script runs *before* the element has been output to the page, which is essentially the same thing as #1. This often occurs if your script is in the `head` of the document instead of at the bottom of the body, for example.

I highly recommend you learn to use your step debugger (in Chrome dev tools, for example), so you can inspect each variable interactively as the code runs; that should hopefully help you see what's going on.

Comment: It turns out that my script was run before the element has been output. I have fixed it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

You have to put your full code in to onload function() of javaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
   // your code
}
```